# How to make prop_search in call_menu automatically show all dropdown list

Tags: python, scripting

I'm creating a menu that lists all materials, but the dropdown list doesn't automatically show, and the user can't type in the search box straight away.
I tried using 'activate_int,' but that doesn't seem to work either. 
Any help would be appreciated

````
import bpy

class MyPropertyGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    pass

class TestMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Add"
    bl_idname = "VIEW3D_MT_select"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
    
        #layout_activate_init = True
        layout.prop_search(scene, "property_select", bpy.data, "materials", icon='VIEWZOOM',  text='')
            
        return {'FINISHED'}

classes = [
    TestMenu,
    MyPropertyGroup,
]

addon_keymaps = []

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.property_select = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyPropertyGroup, name='')

    kc = bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km = kc.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new('wm.call_menu', 'C', 'PRESS', shift=True, ctrl=True)
        kmi.properties.name = TestMenu.bl_idname

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.property_select
    
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
            km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````